# How loop single 'element' in Adobe Edge

Tags: loops, adobe-edge

I am looking for a way to loop the animation of a single element in an Adobe Edge project. I have seen the post telling how to loop the entire animation but I have elements whose timelines are shorter than others, I need it to start looping before the entire animation is over. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is super old, but to anyone else stumpling upon this:
Convert the layer to a symbol, and check the "Autoplay" box. This will give the layer its own timeline, and lets you loop it independently from the main stage.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is [not available in Edge yet.](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/889091)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:
http://www.heathrowe.com/adobe-edge-apply-complete-action-to-loop-an-animation/

you can loop your animation to a timeline point.
cheers